# Good ICs for receiving and decoding FM RDS

Tags: radio, frequency-modulation

I'm interested in doing a project to read [FM RDS data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Data_System). Can anyone recommend good chips for both the FM receiver and RDS decoder?

For an FM receiver, I'd like to be able to control FM frequency (scanning of full range) from a microcontroller.

For the RDS decoder, I'm just interested in an IC that's readily available with a simple interface (e.g. I2C or SPI).

Comment: QN8025 may be just what you are looking for.  But availability is a big problem. You may have to buy it from online sellers like alibaba:http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-1pcs-QN8025-FM-radio-module-alternative-TEA5767-supports-RDS-Radio-Data-System/32325129777.html

In action : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTAw9yoBMq0

Comment: look for RDA5807M module also . It cheap and supports RDS. Note: This  chip uses 3.3v logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies for the lateness in my reply, but there is a project in the [July/August 2010](http://www.elektor.com/magazines/2010/july-047-august/the-elektor-dsp-radio.1391200.lynkx) [just arrived yesterday...] edition of Elektor that may be of interest. It uses the [Si4735](http://www.silabs.com/products/audiovideo/amfmreceivers/Pages/Si473435.aspx) DSP receiver IC that can decode RDS.

Farnell part number for the IC is 1835849

Comment: Thanks for posting that link. I am tempted to have a go myself and make a simple radio. Will add it to the list of 'things to do'... :)